# Excluding the last value in a range from an aggregate calculation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with two columns of data. `A` is monotonically increasing with many duplicates (based on a coarse timestamp), while `B` is essentially random. There are many empty rows at the bottom waiting for future data. It resembles the following:

```
     A   B
 1   5  43
 2   5  77
 3  13   8
 4  21  34
 5  27  68
 6  27  90
 7
 8
 9
10
```

I'm trying to write a few formulae which examine all of the (non-empty) values in a column *except for the last one*. For example, I would like to find the maximum value of `B` excluding the latest value, so the result should be `77` from `B2` instead of `90` from `B6`.

If the values in the range were strictly increasing and unique, I could filter the values of `A` into `C`, excluding any values equal to the maximum value (only the last entry), and then take the `MAX(..)` of that range. However, my data does not have that property; the final value could be duplicated and the duplicates would be inappropriately ignored.

```
     C                             D          E
 1   =FILTER(A:A, A:A < MAX(A:A))  =MAX(C:C)  This produces A4's 21 instead of A5's 27.
```

A similar approach would work if we had a third column of incrementing indices to use:

```
     A   B   C   D                              E
 1   5  43   9   =MAX(FILTER(C:C, A:A <> ""))   Value of index in last populated row.
 2   5  77  10   =MAX(FILTER(A:A, C:C < D1))    Maximum value from a row with lower index.
 3  13   8  11
 4  21  34  12
 5  27  68  13
 6  27  90  14
 7          15
 8          16
 9          17
10          18
```

But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require modifying the original spreadsheet, because that's not always possible. I can't just create a new `IndexSheet` with nothing but an an index column and join it in like this instead...

```
     A   B   C
 1   5  43   =MAX(FILTER(IndexSheet!A:A, A:A <> ""))
 2   5  77   =MAX(FILTER(A:A, IndexSheet!A:A < C1))
...
```

...because that requires that the `IndexSheet` have the same number of rows as the data sheet, and would break as more data is added.

Without modifying the original data sheet, or relying on properties of the data (beyond values being numeric and rows being empty or full), is there any way to perform an aggregate calculation on a range while excluding the last value?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indirect` and `address` formulas to create dynamic range excluding the last row

```
=max(indirect("A1:"&Address(count(A:A)-1,1)))
```

The `count` function gives the number of non empty cells in the column A. You subtract 1 to exclude the last row.

You use that number to build an address using `"A1:"&address(row no, Col no)` which in your example case should be `A1:$A$5`

Use this string to reference your cells using the indirect method `indirect(A1:$A$5)` and pass the reference to the `max` function to determine the max in that range.

Answer (score 1):

From another sheet try:

```
=MAX(Sheet1!B1:indirect("Sheet1!B"&count(Sheet1!B:B)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `FILTER()` and `ROW()` functions to accomplish this:

```
   D
 1 =MAX(FILTER(Data!A:A,
               ROW(Data!A:A) < MAX(FILTER(ROW(Data!A:A),
                                          Data!A:A <> ""))))
```

We use `FILTER(ROW(DATA!A:A), Data!A:A <> ""))` to get an array of row numbers of non-empty rows, and use `MAX(...)` to take the last row number. We use this to exclude the last row by filtering out values from lower row numbers with `FILTER(Data!A:A, ROW(Data!A:A) < ...)`.  We apply `MAX(...)` to this filtered array and get the result we were looking for.